# A metric has positive sectional curvature if and only if ${\rm Ric}_{ij} < \frac{r}{2}g_{ij}$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

It is well known that

> In dimension three a metric has positive sectional curvature if
>   and only if ${\rm Ric}_{ij} < \frac{r}{2}g_{ij}$. where $r$ denotes the scalar curvature.

Is  there a higher dimensional analogues of this theorem?

Comment: Do you mean $Ric <\frac r2 g$ in dimension $3$?

Comment: Yes, its a typo. thanks for your precision.

Comment: I don't think there is a high dimension version. If there is, it would have said that 4d Einstein manifolds (with positive scalar curvature) is of positive sectional curvature, and this is probably not true (I don't immediately have an example, maybe the Kahler case ?).

Comment: Hi @C.F.G , can you provide reference or proof of the statement above?

Comment: @yili: this is corollary 8.2 in [Hamilton paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journalArticle/Download?urlId=10.4310%2Fjdg%2F1214436922)