# what equation $\text{Ric}\le \frac{1}{2}Sg$ implies in three dimension

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be the three manifold with the following equation holds:

$$\text{Ric}\le \frac{1}{2}Sg$$

Which is an analog of the Einstein equation.What does this condition implies for three dimensional case?

I know if the equality holds,the manifold has constant sectional curvature,is there more information about this equation?

Comment: Well, it is straightforward to show $S\geq 0$.

Comment: Do you mean in dimension three $\text{Ric}\le \frac{1}{2}Sg
$ implies $S\ge 0$,what about higher dimension?@DiegoMath

Comment: By the way what does $\text{Ric}\le \frac{1}{2}Sg
$ means ,it means the matrix  $1/2Sg -\text{Ric}$ is positive definite or it means for all $(u,v)$ we have $(1/2Sg -\text{Ric})(u,v)\ge 0$?

Comment: @yili Your second claim makes no sense since replacing $u$ by $-u$, $v$ fixed, would change the sign of the value. An inequality involving the metric is always about quadratic forms: this means $(\frac{1}{2}Sg-\mathrm{Ric})(u,u) \geqslant 0$ for all $u$. Also, DiegoMath's comment is about diemsnion 3

Comment: Oh thank you I see .

Comment: @yili $S\geq0$ for all $n\geq3$. Tracing your inequality you get the condition over scalar curvature.

Comment: [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3227255/272127) and [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331837/a-metric-has-positive-sectional-curvature-if-and-only-if-rm-ric-ij-frac)